# 500 internal server error when I try to access external URL from testcafe scripts

Tags: automated-tests, localhost, internal-server-error, testcafe, web-testing

I'm not able to access the below-mentioned URL through TestCafe. The URL is as mentioned below, which will access a js file.

**https://assets.adobedtm.com/launch-xxxx.min.js**

The same will be accessed as mentioned below

**http://localhost:1337/Kds4rFTmQ!s!utf-8/https://assets.adobedtm.com/launch-xxxx.min.js**

But when I try to access the internal URL, I'm able to access the same.

**https://parentwebsite/xxxx.js**

The same will be accessed as mentioned below.

**http://localhost:1337/Kds4rFTmQ!s!utf-8/https://parentwebsite/xxxx.js**

Please let me know what I can do or where I'm going wrong.

Comment: We are not able to provide any solution without reproducing this issue in action. Could you please provide the page url or an example for reproduction?

Comment: @Artem, the parent website is an internal website we have hosted in our own server. And the adobedtm asset has a JS that gets loaded into our website when we run it. Now when we run the same website using testcafe scripts the adobe URL call in the network tab is showing 500 internal server error.

Comment: @Abhishek, The information you provided is insufficient for me to determine the cause of the issue and find a precise solution. The 500 internal server error can have too many causes and we can't find the exact reason now. Only a real example may show what's going on.

Comment: @AlexSkorkin, Please provide me your email ID i'll provide further details there.

Comment: You can write at suport@devexpress.com.

Comment: @AlexSkorkin, I've dropped a mail, please check

Comment: Thank you. We will look into it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further investigation of the call being made, I found the calls were failing at our firewall and the firewall needed some changes from our end.